# Turning the resulted Page from a repository's `findAll` method into an associative array

Tags: php

Using the eloquent repository library made by [nilportuguess](https://packagist.org/packages/nilportugues/eloquent-repository) I made the following repository:

```
namespace App\Repositories;

use NilPortugues\Foundation\Infrastructure\Model\Repository\Eloquent\EloquentRepository;
use NilPortugues\Foundation\Domain\Model\Repository\Contracts\Identity;
use NilPortugues\Foundation\Domain\Model\Repository\Contracts\Fields;
use NilPortugues\Foundation\Domain\Model\Repository\Contracts\Sort;
use NilPortugues\Foundation\Domain\Model\Repository\Contracts\Pageable;
use NilPortugues\Foundation\Domain\Model\Repository\Contracts\Filter;
use NilPortugues\Foundation\Domain\Model\Repository\Page;

use App\Model\Rover;


class RoverRepository extends EloquentRepository
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function modelClassName()
    {
        return Rover::class;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function find(Identity $id, Fields $fields = null)
    {
        $eloquentModel = parent::find($id, $fields);

        return $eloquentModel->toArray();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function findBy(Filter $filter = null, Sort $sort = null, Fields $fields = null)
    {
        $eloquentModelArray = parent::findBy($filter, $sort, $fields);

        return $this->fromEloquentArray($eloquentModelArray);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function findAll(Pageable $pageable = null)
    {
        $page = parent::findAll($pageable);

        return new Page(
            $this->fromEloquentArray($page->content()),
            $page->totalElements(),
            $page->pageNumber(),
            $page->totalPages(),
            $page->sortings(),
            $page->filters(),
            $page->fields()
        );
    }

    /**
    * @param array $eloquentModelArray
    * @return array
    */
   protected function fromEloquentArray(array $eloquentModelArray) :array
   {
        $results = [];
        foreach ($eloquentModelArray as $eloquentModel) {
            //This is required to handle findAll returning array, not objects.
            $eloquentModel = (object) $eloquentModel;

            $results[] = $eloquentModel->attributesToArray();
        }

        return $results;
   }
}
```

And over my Controller I use the method `findAll()`:

```
$repository=new RoverRepository();
$data=$repository->dinfAll();
```

But how I will be able to turn fetched data into the variable `$sata` as an associative row?

A `var_dump($data)` shows the following:

```
class NilPortugues\Foundation\Domain\Model\Repository\Page#942 (7) {
  protected $elements =>
  class SplFixedArray#941 (0) {
  }
  protected $totalPages =>
  int(1)
  protected $totalElements =>
  int(0)
  protected $pageNumber =>
  int(1)
  protected $sort =>
  class NilPortugues\Foundation\Domain\Model\Repository\Sort#938 (2) {
    protected $properties =>
    NULL
    protected $order =>
    NULL
  }
  protected $filter =>
  class NilPortugues\Foundation\Domain\Model\Repository\Filter#953 (1) {
    protected $filters =>
    NULL
  }
  protected $fields =>
  class NilPortugues\Foundation\Domain\Model\Repository\Fields#940 (1) {
    private $fields =>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is "the data"?

Comment: The retrieved page containing results from the database maped as a `Page` object instance.

Comment: And what do you want to achieve? What's wrong with receiving an array of objects?

Comment: What I want to do it to iterate through the page in cases such as in views or to generate a Rest API response therefore an assosiative array is helpfull in theese cases.

Comment: Well, then you should not return a `Page` object, but rather the data you want to return. Or you should use any of the `get` methods from your `Page` object to get that data